# Как реализовать наклон объекта в tree.js относительно оси, смещенной к его краю

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Есть объект в сцене children[6] его нужно повернуть относительно его же оси, а не глобальной оси координат. Но ось нужно сместить к краю объекта.

[image: выше превью, как хотелось бы чтобы работал поворот]

Comment: А можно ли где-то посмотреть на [mcve]?

Comment: Мой проект https://archivisions.github.io/index.html
копия из https://apps.muellerinc.com/design/

Comment: в проекте apps.muellerinc.com/design ползунок pitch отвечает за наклон крыши. вот его мне и нужно скопировать. (сделать на своем проекте)

Comment: благодарю. стало понятнее )

Comment: Скачал конфигуратор, там нашел main.js http://dropmefiles.com/itTae
там наверняка есть то что нужно. но пока сложно понять как срабатывает изменение угла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безотносительно исходного кода в приведенных ссылках, изменение высоты в зависимости от угла - сплошная тригонометрия:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var roofGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5, 2, 1);
roofGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);

var roof = new THREE.Mesh(roofGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(roof);

var params = {
  pitch: 40
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(params, "pitch", 20, 60).onChange(setHeight);

setHeight(params.pitch);

// Вся магия происходит в этой функции. В нее передается угол (в градусах)
function setHeight(value) {
  let angle = THREE.Math.degToRad(value); // преобразуем градусы в радианы
  // вся суть магии тут - чтобы найти длину противолежащего катета,
  // нужно длину прилежащего катета умножить на тангенс угла
  let height = Math.tan(angle) * 2.5; // 2.5 - половина ширины крыши в проекции на плоскость XZ
  // хак - я знаю, что в моей геометрии 6 точек и те, которые в середине, имеют индексы 1 и 4
  roofGeom.vertices[1].y = height;
  roofGeom.vertices[4].y = height;
  // здесь обязательно нужно ставить этот флаг в true, иначе никакого смещения точек не будет видно
  roofGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  // хороший тон - пересчитать нормали для того, чтобы тени отображались корректно 
  roofGeom.computeFaceNormals();
  roofGeom.computeVertexNormals();
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: курто. а можешь объяснить (в комментариях) построчно или по циклам что - где происходит в твоем коде? СПС!

Comment: @MaxKievSky Обновил ответ. Добавил комментарии в код сниппета.